# Count occurrence of a value combination in R

Tags: r, unique

So I got these two data frames:

```
a <- c('A','B','C')

frame1 <- data.frame(a)

a <- c('A','A','B','B','C','C','C')
b <- c(12,18,120,9,1,7,12)

frame2<- data.frame(a,b)
```

Now I would like to know how many times each unique value in column 'a' occurs in frame2 and add this value to frame1.

The result should look like this:

```
  a c 
1 A 2
2 B 2 
3 C 3
```

Comment: `frame2 %>% count(a)` using `dplyr`.

Comment: or `table(frame2$a)` without additional packages